# IllegalArgumentException after a FragmentTransaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm a beginner in Android development and I've got some trouble doing my first app. I use a view pager that contains 5 fragments. The 5th fragment allows the user to manage his account and fragments 3 and 4 must change when the user logged in with the 5th fragment.

So when user get logged, I ask the 5th fragment to perform the transactions needed for fragment 3 and 4. But when I do that I got an IllegalArgumentException :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b0045 (com.tchatannonce:id/layNotLogged) for fragment AddOffersFragment{44b0be88 #4 id=0x7f0b0045}
```

Here are the code I use to perform the transaction :

**Transaction between frag3 and new Frag :**

```
AddOffersFragment newFrag = new AddOffersFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.layNotLogged, newFrag);
transaction.commit();
```

**Transaction between frag4 and new Frag2 :**

```
MyOffersFragment newFrag2 = new MyOffersFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction2.replace(R.id.layNotLogged2, newFrag2);
transaction2.commit();
```

**And there is the xml used in Frag3 :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layNotLogged"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border_radius"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txv_mustBeLogged"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Vous devez être connecté(e) pour\naccéder à cette fonction"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_goToLogIn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txv_mustBeLogged"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Se Connecter"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that when you are at fragment 5 , fragment 3 does not exist.

Try doing the following in the viewpager initialisation

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)
```

and the documentation for this function is

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It helped a lot, even more than expected correcting other little bugs and this one ^^